# Affinity Propagation method selection

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn affinity propagation algorithm as below.

```
affprop = sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
```

I also have a similarity matrix created for the data I am using. Now I want to use my similarity matrix to use in the affinity propagation model.

In sklearn they have different methods for this such as fit, fit_predict, predict. So, I'm not sure what to use.

Is it correct if I use,

```
affprop.fit(my similarity matrix)
```

Please suggest me what suits me most?

Comment: There is a tutorial where they discuss aspects of fitness and prediction.

Comment: can you tell me its name? :)

Comment: "scikit-learn tutorial" works for me as search terms.